# updateValueAndValidity does not work on particular formControl

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation, angular-formbuilder

after I dynamically add the form control, the `rrp.invalid` does not work when the input is `touched`. It works in case if I write something and remove it.

Initially, it works well, but when I remove `rrp` form control and add it dynamically, it does not work as expected

component ts file

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        rrp: ['', [Validators.required]],
        priceType: [PricingType.Fixed, []],
    });

    this.form.get('priceType').valueChanges.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
        debounceTime(500)
    ).subscribe((chosenPriceType) => {
        this.managePricingControls(chosenPriceType);
    });
}

private managePricingControls(priceType: string) {
    switch(priceType) {
        case PricingType.Fixed:
            this.addFixedPriceControls();
            break;
        case PricingType.Subscription:
            this.removeFixedPriceControls();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private addFixedPriceControls() {
    this.form.addControl(
        'rrp',
        this.fb.control(0, Validators.required)
    );
    this.form.get('rrp').updateValueAndValidity()
    this.form.addControl(
        'expiresInMonth',
        this.fb.control(0)
    );
}

get rrp() {
    return this.form.get('rrp');
}
```

template

```html
<div *ngIf="rrp" class="form-group required">

  <label for="rrp" title="Recommended Retail Price">RRP</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control "
    id="rrp"
    formControlName="rrp"
    appPositiveNumber
    [decimal]="true"
    [decimalNumbers]="2"
    autocomplete="off"
  >
  <span class="currency">{{currency}}</span>

  <div *ngIf="rrp?.invalid && (rrp?.dirty || rrp?.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    Recommended Retail Price is required
  </div>

</div>
```

note: I've tried to put `setTimeout(() => this.form.get('rrp').updateValueAndValidity(), 0);` as well

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is that I pass validation in the wrong way. Instead of

```js
this.form.addControl(
  'rrp',
  this.fb.control('', Validators.required)
);
```

I should've add the control like below:

```js
this.form.addControl(
  'rrp',
  this.fb.control('', [Validators.required])
);
```

The `Validators.required` as element of array.